# Efficient way to transform array into encoding for ordinal regression

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this array

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([2, 3, 4])
```

And I would like to map that to

```
[array([ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.])]
```

This is the best solution I've found so far

```
def ordinal_array(where_max, array_len=5):
    return np.hstack((np.ones((where_max)), np.zeros((array_len-where_max))))

list(map(ordinal_array,[2,3,4]))
```

But I would like to know if there's something that scales better since I would like apply this to arrays that have a few million data points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) with greater-than `outer-comparison` of input array against the range of `array_len` values -

```
In [14]: array
Out[14]: array([2, 3, 4])

In [15]: array_len = 5

In [16]: (array[:,None] > np.arange(array_len)).astype(float)
Out[16]: 
array([[1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

With NumPy built-in -

```
In [23]: np.greater.outer(array, np.arange(array_len)).astype(float)
Out[23]: 
array([[1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

For performance, consider converting to lower precision `int` or even keeping the output as boolean array (skip astype conversion for this).

Answer (score 0):

I think creating whole matrix in the beginning can make it faster. Look at f2 function below.

```
import random
import numpy as np

def ordinal_array(where_max, array_len=5):
    return np.hstack((np.ones((where_max)), np.zeros((array_len-where_max))))

def f1(arr):
  return list(map(ordinal_array,arr))

def f2(arr):
  n = len(arr)
  retval = np.zeros((n, 5))
  for i in range(n):
    no = arr[i]
    retval[i, 0:no] = 1
  return list(retval)

a = [random.randint(0, 5) for i in range(100000)]

%timeit f1(a)
%timeit f2(a)
```

It seems faster for 100000 items.

> 1 loop, best of 3: 816 ms per loop
>
> 10 loops, best of 3: 95.7 ms per loop

It may even possible to reduce for loop in the f2 function.